# Returning the position of an element from a vector with nested if statements in R

Tags: r

I have a vector of random letters and I am trying to find out where they spell a word pass. let is the vector with a bunch of random letters in it.
I have began with the for (i in 1:length(let)){
if(let[i] =="p") and I am unsure what to do after this.If you guys could give me some advice on what to do I would appreciate it.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and the desired output.

Comment: `& let[i + 1] == "a"`...

Answer (score 0):

```
results<-c()
for (i in 1:length(let)) { 
  if(let[i] =="p"
     & let[i+1] =="a"
     & let[i+2] =="s"
     & let[i+3] =="s"){
    results[i] <- TRUE
  } else {results[i] <- FALSE
  }
}
```